# Regex pattern matching for ; and / on multiple lines

Tags: regex, perl

I just started learning Perl today, and I am working with regular expressions to match text from within a file.

I am checking to see if my file contains.

```
     / 
;
```

This is what I have attempted so far:

```
if ($Text =~ /;\n//)
{
  //dostuff
}
```

Is this syntax correct? Do I need to use the \n or is there a character for end of line? Also, can I search for / or do I need some sort of escape character?

Comment: What happens when you try running the code you've posted? (The results should answer 2 of your 3 questions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search for `/` you have to escape it with `\`.

To check your example however, you need to turn it around because you want to match the `/` before the `;`.
In the end it should look like this: `if ($Text =~ /\/\n;/)`

For more information, see [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) to get an introduction
to regular expressions in Perl.

Comment: The modifier `m` changes the behavior of `^` and `$` and the modifier `s` changes the behavior of `.`. Thus the `/ms` will have no effect in this case.

Comment: Thank you! And I will make sure to bookmark the link.

Comment: You can avoid (or reduce) [LTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) by using an alternate delimiter: `$foo =~ m{/\n;}`

Answer (score 1):

Use a backslash to escape your forward slash. Also why are you trying to match it in reverse order? Try `$Text =~ /\/\n;/`.

Comment: Thank you! I must have accidentally reversed the two when I was attempting.